# Writing a List instance to Excel file - Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a `List` of `String` objects that are pipe delimited. something like this:

```
String1|String2|String3
String4|String5|String6
...
```

Using Apache POI as excel library, is it possible to iterate over entire List writing out the string object as each row in the excel file?  i.e. something like:

```
for (String inst : <List instance>)
       <sheetInstance>.write(inst)
```

i.e. output the string directly to the excel as a row entry rather than setting each cell value with a string i.e.

> ```
> setting row 1, cell 1 = String1
> setting row 1, cell 2 = String2
> setting row 1, cell 3 = String3
> setting row 2, cell 1 = String4 ...
> ```

Currently, it looks like I need to set individual cells to each value.

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question, but as far as I know, you have to do the writing on a cell basis. It is not possible to write in a row into subsequent cells, at least it wasn't when I last used POI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to split the `String` into an array in order to fill the cells, like this:

```java
for (short rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < stringList.length(); rowIndex++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex);
    String[] cellValues = stringList.get(rowIndex).split("|");
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < cellValues.length; colIndex++) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(colIndex);
        cell.setCellValue(cellValues[colIndex]);
    }
}
```