# How to Write a list of value objects directly into Excel file without iterating every single column?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a scenario that I want to write a list of Value Objects like:

```
public class RequestHandlerVo {

private String userSoeID;
private String email;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String publicationReceived;
private String sourceOfUnsubscribe;
private String senderEmail;
private String receivedDateFrom;
private String receivedDateTo;
private String apiName;
private String updatedBy;
private String updatedOn;
private String action;
}
```

into an excelsheet without using this logic:

```
Set<Integer> keyset = hashmap.keySet();
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream( new File(path));
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream( new File(path));
    int rownum = 1;
    int cellnum = 0;

    initializeExcelFile(hashmap,path);

    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inp);

    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

    for(Integer key : keyset){
        List<String> nameList = hashmap.get(key);
        for(String s : nameList){
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rownum++);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(cellnum);
            if(null!=cell){
                cell.setCellValue(s);
            }
        }
        cellnum++;
        rownum=1;
    }

    workbook.write(out);
```

because I have thousands of records and this logic leads me to over 100k iterations. It is taking 92 seconds to write 1035 records in a excel file.

I have gone through:
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251432/writing-a-list-instance-to-excel-file-apache-poi),[Write data into Excel sheet java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361115/write-data-into-excel-sheet-java]) and [How list has map values write to excel file using Apache poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135152/how-list-has-map-values-write-to-excel-file-using-apache-poi])

But did not get the solution.

Comment: Did you try profiling your application? Are you sure it's really Apache POI that's being slow? Did you [follow the advice on the POI faq entry on performance](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10165)?

Comment: I think here is your answer, https://www.jeejava.com/generic-way-of-writing-data-in-excel-using-apache-poi/

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with CSV or other file format, you can try this. The below example writes a CSV file from an ArrayList with single line of code.

You can modify it as per your input source type.

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
// add data to arrray list

Path out = Paths.get("filename.csv");
Files.write(out, data, Charset.defaultCharset());
```